Need Some Advice on Cutting Cork
Just wanted to know how everyone would approach this. I'm currently making a small shelf to go on my desk. One part of the shelf requires me to create a drawer with a cork base. I am trying to create small divots in the cork so I can place things like pencils, notebooks, etc. Example inspiration is attached. Btw I have a 1/2 inch thick cork board. I also don't have a router.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I think you might want to make it clearer that you're looking to create recesses in your 1/2" cork, "divot" to me reads more like much smaller impressions than you're going for. Anyway, FWIW I don't think there's any reasonable way you'll do this without a router, unless you change things up — by using a lamination of two sheets. You cut right through the top one (which only requires a sharp boxcutter and a steel rule), then glue that to your second piece to form recesses instead of cutting/milling them into solid material as we would tend to do in wood.

Hand gouges could do this.  In fact, even though I've got a couple routers, I'd be wondering if a router might tear up cork.  A razor sharp hand gouge would give you more control.

A sharp router bit with the right feeds and speeds can usually mill cork no problem. While cutting with a sharp gouge is theoretically doable getting a clean bottom is going to be essentially impossible IME. Cork is very yielding, presenting an even worse potential for the sort of crumbling than the very soft/spongy earlywood of spruce or similar softwoods.
